# Obj-C, trying to write an alternative to NSLog, but I want my function to concatenate like NSLog?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've decided it would be easiest if I replace my NSLog calls with another function....

```
+(void)logThis:(NSString*)line{ 

#ifdef DEBUG 
NSLog(line); 
#endif  

}
```

However, I'm going to have to replace 215 NSLog calls, it would be a lot quicker if my function accepted multiple paramaters like NSLog, then all I would have to do is find and replace NSLog with my function name / class, then the extra bracket to a square bracket.

Can anyone tell me now I can add such parameter acceptance into my function ?

OR a quicker / better solution, which wouldn't mean adding more lines of code instead of NSLog ?

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer to your previous question; it links to how to use a macro to have a drop-in replacement for NSLog().

Comment: http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/ - read down to DLog.

Comment: you should always use a string literal as your first argument to NSLog, even if it's as simple as: `NSLog(@"%@",line);`. if you use the variadic approach, then you'll also want to know about `NSLogv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). These functions take a flexible number of arguments, like `NSLog`, `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]`, etc.

See this tutorial:

http://www.numbergrinder.com/node/35

Comment: +1 very useful tutorial (and probably better than macro hacks, because it leaves the option of turning logging on/off at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

How about making a macro "NSLOG_IF_DEBUGGING" that expands to "NSLog" or "(void)", depending on whether or not it's a debugging build? Then you would just globally replace all your NSLog calls with NSLOG_IF_DEBUGGING.