# Variable length parameters in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, methods, variadic

How can i make a class method with variable length parameters, in Objective-C?

For example, a method like -arrayWithObjects:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a variadic function. These functions take a flexible number of arguments, like `NSLog`, `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]`, etc.

See this tutorial:

http://www.numbergrinder.com/node/35

Copied from my answer here: [Obj-C, trying to write an alternative to NSLog, but I want my function to concatenate like NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864901/obj-c-trying-to-write-an-alternative-to-nslog-but-i-want-my-function-to-concate/4864998#4864998)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at varargs, e.g.:
[Apple Technical Q&A QA1405](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html). It shouldn't matter whether the method is a class method or not.

Answer (score 3):

Methods that take variable arguments are known as variadic methods. The "..." is the variable argument.
For example, your function declaration would be: `- (void)specialWithX:(NSInteger)x y:(NSInteger)y, ...;`

For additional information take a look at [Variable argument lists in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html)