# How to make method like UIActionSheet initWithTitle

Tags: objective-c, optional-parameters

How can i make method with parameter is unlimited array like this :

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc]
                initWithTitle:@"Test Title"
                delegate:self
                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive"
                otherButtonTitles: @"abc", @"xyz",
                nil] autorelease];
```

In above code, parameter otherButtonTitles can have unlimit number of NSString like "abc", "xyz",..
Can do this with other type of parameter?
Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5458428/971401).

Comment: other type of parameter ? what do u mean? instead of giving it here like a string , you want to explicitly give any data type through an array is it?

Comment: elaborate your question a little more

Comment: Vince's answer is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with any type of object.

In the header

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSObject *)first, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

Implementation

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSObject *)first, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, first);
    for (NSObject *o = first; o!=nil; o = va_args(args,NSObject*)) {
        NSLog(@"Here's your next object: %@", o);
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```