# Variable number of method parameters in Objective C - Need an example

Tags: objective-c, parameters, optional-parameters

From [Objective C Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html) (Under the "Object Messaging" section),

> Methods that take a variable number of parameters are also possible,
> though they’re somewhat rare. Extra parameters are separated by commas
> after the end of the method name. (Unlike colons, the commas are not
> considered part of the name.) In the following example, the imaginary
> makeGroup: method is passed one required parameter (group) and three
> parameters that are optional:
>
> [receiver makeGroup:group, memberOne, memberTwo, memberThree];

I tried to create such a method and it shows an error

***"Expected ';' after method prototype"***

when I try to declare the below function in my interface file(.h file).

```
- (void) printMyClass: (int) x, (int) y, (int) z;
```

Can anyone give sample example to create such a method like `makeGroup`

Thank you

Comment: do you only want a fixed N number of parameters or do you want it to be a variable N (i.e. x, y, z and possibly letters after that?)?

Comment: See [Technical Q&A 1405, How can I write a method that takes a variable number of arguments, like `+\[NSString stringWithFormat:\]?](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable length parameters in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458428/variable-length-parameters-in-objective-c)

Comment: Fixed N numbers of parameters.. It will be good if you also leave a note about how-to-do the variable N parameter(dynamic number of parameters)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can see this [link](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/09/creating-and-implementing-custom-method.html).

In your header file define the methods with three dots at the end

```
-(void)yourMethods:(id)string1,...;
```

And in you implementation file write the methods body

```
-(void)yourMethods:(id)string1, ...{

    NSMutableArray *arguments=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:nil];
    id eachObject;
    va_list argumentList;
    if (string1) 
    {
        [arguments addObject: string1];
        va_start(argumentList, string1); 
        while ((eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)))    
        {
             [arguments addObject: eachObject];
        }
        va_end(argumentList);        
     }
    NSLog(@"%@",arguments);
}
```

Now call your method

```
[self yourMethods:@"ab",@"cd",@"ef",@"gf",nil];
```

NOTE: remember to put **nil** at the end

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, Should I use "NSMutableArray" to implement the multiple parameters in method?

Comment: Sorry i dint understand your question. Where do u want to use mutable array, while calling the method or inside the body of the method?...You can see the link above where the expalination has been done

Comment: Sorry.. I confused little bit. So the yourMethods method and methodWithVariableParameters method is same?

Comment: what if argument is not of kind id?? for example a BOOL: '[self yourMethods:@"ab", 1,nil];'
help me here please..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I want to call this method in another method which also takes variable number of method parameters and need to pass these parameters to the called method, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for declaring a method with a variable number of arguments is like this:

```
- (void) printMyClass: (int) x, ...;
```

One argument is always the required minimum, the others can be accessed via the `va_arg` function group. For the exact details, see [this tutorial](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/12/variable-arguments-varargs-in-objective-c/).